# HOw to install extensions on chrome When extensions link is closed

Tags: google-chrome

Here extensions link is closed in chrome. How can I install extensions from out side the store

Comment: open google chrome ~ settings by drag and drop

Comment: This is completely offtopic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can go with the steps.

1. Click on the link https://crx.dam.io/ --> The link provides +129,026 extensions
2. Search for your extension
3. Click on any of the links to download any version you want.
4. The downloaded file will be in ZIP format.
5. Extract the zip folder
6. Then go to extensions in chrome. Or simply type this: chrome://extensions/
7. Then check the Developer mode checkbox
8. And click on Pack extensions
9. Next you click on browse for Extension root directory: the downloaded files which was extracted in step 5.
10. Then click on pack extension
11. It will generate two files (.crx) and (.pem) in the specified folder.
12. Go to the folder and drag .crx file and drop it in extensions page.
13. After a while it will prompt an alert. just click on Add extension.